# Create count visualizations with PHP and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5.8

I´m traying to create a function for count visualizations of my post. But I need to check `ip` and if `ip` is more then hour don´t show the post, add one visualization. But, if  `ip` in less then hour show post twice and don´t add visualization.

My actual code is:

```
public function countVisualization($id){
        $visualizations = Blog::select('visualization')->where('id', $id)->get();

        /** 
         * get ip from client and update visualization only
         * if the time it´s higher to 60min
         */
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        $visualizations = ($visualizations[0]->visualization + 1);

        $actualDate = new \DateTime();
        echo $actualDate->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

        Visualizations::create(["ip" => $ip, "created_at" => $actualDate, 'updated_at' => $actualDate]);

        $same = Visualizations::where('ip', '=', $ip)->first();

        print_r($same[0]);

        exit();

        $result = \DB::table('blogs')->where('id', $id)->update(['visualization' => $visualizations]);

        return \Redirect::back();
    }
```

But now I don´t know how to check this... I add my `ip` and my date in timestamp data DB, but I don´t know how can I check if an hour has passed and use `$visualizations` to add one visualization in my post. First that you show post, add perfectly.

Thanks for help, and sorry for my English.

**update**

```
public function countVisualization($id){
        $visualizations = Blog::select('visualization')->where('id', $id)->get();

        //Get user's IP 
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $nowMinus1hour = $now->subHour();
        Visualizations::create(["ip" => $ip, "created_at" => $now, 'updated_at' => $now]);
        
        //Check if there is an entry of this IP in last 1 hour.
        $visualizationHistory = Visualizations::where('ip', '=', $ip)->where('created_at', '>=', $nowMinus1hour)->where('created_at', '<', $now)->first();

        print_r($visualizationHistory);
        exit();

        /*if(!empty($visualizationHistory)) {
            Visualizations::create(["ip" => $ip, "created_at" => $actualDate, 'updated_at' => $actualDate]);



        $result = \DB::table('blogs')->where('id', $id)->update(['visualization' => $visualizations]);

        return \Redirect::back();*/
    }
```

Comment: You want to show the post maximum 2 times if accessed from the same IP, in case more the post is accessed/ showed twice within an hour you don't want to show it. Right?

Comment: no, i want show post always, but register visualization 1 hourly if it´s same ip

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something like this-

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use \Carbon\Carbon;

public function countVisualization(Request $request, $id){
    $visualization = Blog::select('visualization')->where('id', $id)->first();
    
    //Get user's IP 
    $ip = $request->ip();
    
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $nowMinus1hour = $now->subHour();
    
    //Check if there is an entry of this IP in last 1 hour.
    $visualizationHistory = Visualizations::where('ip', '=', $ip)->where('created_at', '>=', $nowMinus1hour)->where('created_at', '<', $now)->first();

    if(!empty($visualizationHistory)) {
        
        //found, logic to show the post
    }else {
        //Not found, update the $visualizations
        $visualization->visualization = $visualization->visualization++;
        $visualization->save();

    }

    return \Redirect::back();
}
```

Comment: thaks for your response, but i need insert one first time, in my code line "create" but after i need check ip. $visualizationHistory don´t return nothing if i sum 1 hour in db i edit my question with my actual code